# Morph SVG with <animate> SVG or CSS transition

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transitions, svg-animate

I'm struggling to make an animation work. I've created two SVG shapes in Illustrator with the same amount of path points. Now i want to code a morphing animation. My first try was an animate object as suggested [here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/):

```html
<span class="svgspan">
              <svg class="svg1" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 398 369.4"
                style="enable-background:new 0 0 398 369.4;" xml:space="preserve">
                <style type="text/css">
                  .st0 {
                    fill: #FFFFFF;
                  }
                </style>
                <path id="pfad" class="st0" d="M398 184.7c0 51-20.7 97.2-54.1 130.6s-79.6 54.1-130.6 54.1s-97.2-20.7-130.6-54.1s-54.1-79.6-54.1-130.6
                        S49.3 87.5 82.7 54.1S162.3 0 213.3 0s97.2 20.7 130.6 54.1S398 133.7 398 184.7z">
                <animate id="trs" begin="500ms" fill="freeze" attributename="d" dur="2s" from ="M398,184.7c0,51-20.7,97.2-54.1,130.6s-79.6,54.1-130.6,54.1s-97.2-20.7-130.6-54.1s-54.1-79.6-54.1-130.6
                S49.3 87.5 82.7 54.1S162.3 0 213.3 0s97.2 20.7 130.6 54.1S398 133.7 398 184.7z" to="M195 369.4c-48.4-78-140.4-118.3-182.3-200.3C-3.8 131.7-6.1 85 17.2 50C57.9-16 157.7-15.8 199.1 49.4
                        c32.3-51.6 107.8-65.7 155.7-27.5c54.5 39.2 53.8 119.8 15.8 170.4c-49 65.4-124.1 107-167.6 177.1H195z"></path>
              </svg></span>
```

I got an animation, but it didn't morph but instantly switch to the second path.

My next approach was a [css animation](https://css-tricks.com/animate-svg-path-changes-in-css/) like this:

```css
#pfad {
  d: path('M195,369.4c-48.4-78-140.4-118.3-182.3-200.3C-3.8,131.7-6.1,85,17.2,50C57.9-16,157.7-15.8,199.1,49.4c32.3-51.6,107.8-65.7,155.7-27.5c54.5,39.2,53.8,119.8,15.8,170.4c-49,65.4-124.1,107-167.6,177.1H195z');
  transition: 1s;
}
```

This didn't work either. I even got an 'Unknown property: d' error in VS Code and Chrome:

[image: Chrome Error]
[image: VS Code Error]

It would be nice if someone could help me get this working.

Edit: The anchor points are in the right position now i guess, but i still have the same problem. New anchor points:

````html
<path id="pfad" class="st0" d="M199,369.4c-57.6-0.5-110.6-27.4-144.1-69.2c-25.4-31.6-40.6-71.8-40.6-115.5C14.3,82.7,97,0,199,0
                s184.7,82.7,184.7,184.7c0,33.7-9,65.3-24.8,92.5C326.9,332.3,267.3,369.4,199,369.4C198.4,369.4,199.6,369.4,199,369.4z">
                <animate id="trs" begin="500ms" fill="freeze" attributename="d" dur="2s" from ="M199,369.4c-57.6-0.5-110.6-27.4-144.1-69.2c-25.4-31.6-40.6-71.8-40.6-115.5C14.3,82.7,97,0,199,0
                s184.7,82.7,184.7,184.7c0,33.7-9,65.3-24.8,92.5C326.9,332.3,267.3,369.4,199,369.4C198.4,369.4,199.6,369.4,199,369.4z" to="M199,369.4C150.6,291.4,54.8,251,12.9,169C-3.6,131.6-5.9,84.9,17.4,49.9c40.7-66,140.5-65.8,181.9-0.6
                C231.6-2.3,307.1-16.4,355,21.8c54.5,39.2,53.8,119.8,15.8,170.4C321.8,257.6,242.5,299.3,199,369.4L199,369.4z"></path>```
````

Comment: Also which browser did you use, cross-browser support it not universal.

Comment: Yes, they do have the same number of points. At least when i exported it from illustrator. I use Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159

Comment: The path commands are not the same as the animate commands. E.g. animate ends cccz but the path ends SSSz. They have to be the same letters to animate smoothly.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ah okay thanks. What would be a way to achieve this? Would it be enough to just get one path point to be at the same coordinate in both shapes in illustrator? I assume just editing the letters would lead to a different shape.

Comment: No idea, I've never used illustrator. If I was doing this I'd likely create the paths either by hand or via Inkscape.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try that!

Comment: Try the GSAP library which has a powerful morphing plugin. Also I recommend that you edit or recreate your svgs with Inkscape which will bring cleaner and more friendly svg code.

Comment: I've now managed to get the anchor points right but still am seeing the same behavior.

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS Thanks! I'll definitely try that even though i would prefer the html/css-only version.

Answer (score 3):

Like the comments suggest, it is a good idea to be precise with the point in the path. So, your code is ok. It is just the path that need a helping hand.

I copied your path to Inkscape and make the two shapes there.

```css
path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="svgspan">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="200" height="200">
    <path id="pfad" class="st0"
      d="M 500,1000 C 220,1000 0,780 0,500 0,220 220,0 500,0 c 280,0 500,220 500,500 0,280 -220,500 -500,500 z">
      <animate id="trs" begin="1s" fill="freeze" attributename="d" dur="2s"
       from ="M 500,1000 C 220,1000 0,780 0,500 0,220 220,0 500,0 c 280,0 500,220 500,500 0,280 -220,500 -500,500 z"
       to="M 500,1000 C 420,820 0,600 0,300 0,0 380,-120 500,150 620,-120 1000,0 1000,300 c 0,300 -420,520 -500,700 z" />
    </path>
  </svg>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

***The main condition for the implementation of smooth animation path changes

using the attribute `d` are:***

1. Equal number of nodes in both shapes
2. Exact match of the node type (A; C; Q), respectively, for each point in the initial and final position of the path
   These conditions can be met in different ways, but it is better to do this in the vector editor.

You must have the same number of node points by the heart and the circle

Below is a screenshot from Inkscape. Drag matching points from the outline of the heart to the outline of the circle

[image]

***@chrwahl*** did this work in his answer while solving this problem
All credits to @chrwahl for a job well done

@jayjay9601 [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944695/morph-svg-with-animate-css-transition#)

> I'll definitely try that even though i would prefer the html/css-only
> version

Below is the complete CSS animation code using the `d` attribute:

```css
.svgspan {
width:30vw;
height:30vh;
}
#pfad{
  fill: crimson;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#pfad:hover {
d: path("M 500,1000 C 420,820 0,600 0,300 0,0 380,-120 500,150 620,-120 1000,0 1000,300 c 0,300 -420,520 -500,700 z"); 
fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgspan">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" >
    <path id="pfad" class="st0"
      d="M 500,1000 C 220,1000 0,780 0,500 0,220 220,0 500,0 c 280,0 500,220 500,500 0,280 -220,500 -500,500 z">
      
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```